# regex find what's after slash without showing the slash

Tags: python, regex

I have a script that split the informations in a line, i've succeeded to split it and extract the informations i need but i have the slash that shows up :/ i'de like to get only what's after it here's an example:

```
import re 

data = "12:05:12.121    O:CLASS (SMS:/xxx.xxx@xxx.xx) R:VOICE/1654354 mid:4312" 
ms = re.match(r'(\S+).*mid:(\d+)', data) # extract time and mid 
k = re.findall(r"/\S+", data ) # extract source and destination 
result = { 'time':ms.group(1), 'mid':ms.group(2), "source":k[0],"Destination":k[1]}

print result
```

and here's the result `{'source': '/xxx.xxx@xxx.xx)', 'Destination':'/1654354', 'mid':'4312','time':'12.05.12.121'}`

and the result i want is without slash like here:

```
{'source': 'xxx.xxx@xxx.xx)', 'Destination':'1654354', 'mid':'4312','time':'12.05.12.121'}
```

Comment: no no i just mistyped actually it doesn't show it like that i've edited it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the `\S+` in a capturing group:

```
k = re.findall(r"/(\S+)", data)
```

And here's another way of getting that info all with one regex:

```
import re 

data = "12:05:12.121      O:CLASS (SMS:/xxx.xxx@xxx.xx) R:VOICE/1654354 mid:4312" 
result = re.search(r'''
      (?P<time>.*?)
      \s+
      .*?
      \s+
      \(
          (?P<type>.*?):/(?P<source>.*?)
      \)
      \s+
      .*/(?P<destination>\d+)
      \s+
      mid:(?P<mid>\d+)
''', data, re.VERBOSE)

print result.groupdict()
```

Comment: and what if i want to get what's before the slash ?? ( just for my learning ) like in the example i want to get SMS and VOICE

Comment: `\((.*?):/(.*?)\)` should get both of them into two capturing groups.

Comment: i've tested it and it's not working, maybe u didn't get my question. 
what i mean was to get a result like, {'source': 'xxx.xxx@xxx.xx,'typeS':'SMS', 'Destination':'1654354', 'TypeD':'VOICE', 'mid':'4312','time':'12.05.12.121'}

Comment: @SkivlageLatif: You're asking too much for a simple question. I'm sure you're more than capable of writing it.

Comment: Thank you buti doubt so lol, i've just started learning Python 3 days ago so i'm still not very familiar with it :/ thank you for your help!

Comment: You're SOLUTION IS SO GREAT i like how it works but i didn't really understood how it works :/